# Conflicting jquery NPM packages

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm, npm-install

I have a project that uses Angular2, webpack, and NPM on Windows. I am experiencing this on both v4.2.0 and v5.3.0 of NPM.

It appears sometimes I get the official jquery package and my build works. Othertimes I get an unofficial package from [coolaj86](https://github.com/UncoolAJ86/node-jquery/issues/17#issuecomment-2083588) and then my build breaks with missing dependencies.

Even if I only use `npm install git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#f5416725afef` to install directly from the official repo, I still randomly get either package (and sometimes 1.7.4).

I can sit and run the same npm install command over and over and it will randomly rotate through different actual packages installed. I'm so confused..

It could also be related to a jquery-color package I use depending on jQuery (note the capital 'Q') 1.7.4 because that also sometimes ends up being the jquery package I get in `node_modules`.

In my `package.json` I reference jquery (I have also tried `git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#f5416725afef` here):

```
"jquery": "2.2.4"
```

Sometimes my `node_modules\jquery\package.json` file is this, and the build works. This appears to be the official package.

```
{
  "_args": [
    [
      {
        "raw": "jquery@2.2.4",
        "scope": null,
        "escapedName": "jquery",
        "name": "jquery",
        "rawSpec": "2.2.4",
        "spec": "2.2.4",
        "type": "version"
      },
      "C:\\dev\\MyProject"
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "jquery@2.2.4",
  "_id": "jquery@2.2.4",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_location": "/jquery",
  "_nodeVersion": "0.10.45",
  "_npmOperationalInternal": {
    "host": "packages-16-east.internal.npmjs.com",
    "tmp": "tmp/jquery-2.2.4.tgz_1463765166836_0.5834389675874263"
  },
  "_npmUser": {
    "name": "timmywil",
    "email": "timmywillisn@gmail.com"
  },
  "_npmVersion": "2.15.1",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "raw": "jquery@2.2.4",
    "scope": null,
    "escapedName": "jquery",
    "name": "jquery",
    "rawSpec": "2.2.4",
    "spec": "2.2.4",
    "type": "version"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "/",
    "/bootstrap-colorpicker",
    "/ion-rangeslider",
    "/jquery-validation"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery/-/jquery-2.2.4.tgz",
  "_shasum": "2c89d6889b5eac522a7eea32c14521559c6cbf02",
  "_shrinkwrap": null,
  "_spec": "jquery@2.2.4",
  "_where": "C:\\dev\\MyProject",
  "author": {
    "name": "jQuery Foundation and other contributors",
    "url": "https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.2.4/AUTHORS.txt"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues"
  },
  "commitplease": {
    "components": [
      "Docs",
      "Tests",
      "Build",
      "Release",
      "Core",
      "Ajax",
      "Attributes",
      "Callbacks",
      "CSS",
      "Data",
      "Deferred",
      "Deprecated",
      "Dimensions",
      "Effects",
      "Event",
      "Manipulation",
      "Offset",
      "Queue",
      "Selector",
      "Serialize",
      "Traversing",
      "Wrap"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "description": "JavaScript library for DOM operations",
  "devDependencies": {
    "commitplease": "2.0.0",
    "core-js": "0.9.17",
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-babel": "5.0.1",
    "grunt-cli": "0.1.13",
    "grunt-compare-size": "0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "0.6.1",
    "grunt-git-authors": "2.0.1",
    "grunt-jscs": "2.1.0",
    "grunt-jsonlint": "1.0.4",
    "grunt-npmcopy": "0.1.0",
    "gzip-js": "0.3.2",
    "jsdom": "5.6.1",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "1.0.0",
    "qunit-assert-step": "1.0.3",
    "qunitjs": "1.17.1",
    "requirejs": "2.1.17",
    "sinon": "1.10.3",
    "sizzle": "2.2.1",
    "strip-json-comments": "1.0.3",
    "testswarm": "1.1.0",
    "win-spawn": "2.0.0"
  },
  "directories": {},
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "2c89d6889b5eac522a7eea32c14521559c6cbf02",
    "tarball": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery/-/jquery-2.2.4.tgz"
  },
  "gitHead": "c0185ab7c75aab88762c5aae780b9d83b80eda72",
  "homepage": "http://jquery.com",
  "keywords": [
    "jquery",
    "javascript",
    "browser",
    "library"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/jquery.js",
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "dmethvin",
      "email": "dave.methvin@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "scott.gonzalez",
      "email": "scott.gonzalez@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "m_gol",
      "email": "m.goleb@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "timmywil",
      "email": "timmywillisn@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "name": "jquery",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm install && grunt",
    "start": "grunt watch",
    "test": "grunt && grunt test"
  },
  "title": "jQuery",
  "version": "2.2.4"
}
```

Other time my `node_modules\jquery\package.json` file is this, and the build breaks with missing dependencies. This appears to be the unofficial build from [coolaj86](https://github.com/UncoolAJ86/node-jquery/issues/17#issuecomment-2083588).

```
{
  "__dependencies": {
    "jsdom": "~0.2.14",
    "htmlparser": "1.7.6",
    "xmlhttprequest": "~1.4.2",
    "location": "0.0.1",
    "navigator": "~1.0.1"
  },
  "__devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.3.8",
    "nodeunit": "~0.7.4"
  },
  "_args": [
    [
      "jquery@2.2.4",
      "C:\\dev\\MyProject"
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "jquery@2.2.4",
  "_id": "jquery@2.2.4",
  "_inBundle": false,
  "_integrity": "sha1-LInWiJterFIqfuoywUUhVZxsvwI=",
  "_location": "/jquery",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "type": "version",
    "registry": true,
    "raw": "jquery@2.2.4",
    "name": "jquery",
    "escapedName": "jquery",
    "rawSpec": "2.2.4",
    "saveSpec": null,
    "fetchSpec": "2.2.4"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "/",
    "/bootstrap-colorpicker",
    "/ion-rangeslider",
    "/jquery-validation"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery/-/jquery-2.2.4.tgz",
  "_spec": "2.2.4",
  "_where": "C:\\dev\\MyProject",
  "author": {
    "name": "James Morrin",
    "email": "treasonx@gmail.com"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery/issues"
  },
  "description": "jQuery: The Write Less, Do More, JavaScript Library (packaged for Node.JS)",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.6"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery",
  "keywords": [
    "util",
    "dom",
    "jquery"
  ],
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery/blob/master/LICENSE-MIT"
    }
  ],
  "main": "lib/node-jquery",
  "name": "jquery",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  },
  "url": "http://jquery.com",
  "version": "2.2.4"
}
```

If I call `npm install` multiple times, it will often switch to the other jquery package, but not always, and this is making continuous integration impossible. Is there any way I can force npm to install the official package every time? Or to redirect dependencies on jQuery to the later jquery package?

Currently I'm clobbering the node_modules\jquery directory with a zipped up copy I took at a point when I had the right one. It works, but yuck.

Here is the output of `npm config list`:

```
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/5.3.0 node/v8.2.1 win32 x64"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\[username]\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = F:\BuildAgent1\work\5a4db8c598978904\Web\MyProject
; HOME = C:\Users\[username]
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

Here's the entire `package.json` for my project:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build:vendor": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js  --progress --profile --bail --env.prod",
    "build:vendor:dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js  --progress --profile",
    "build:prod": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js  --progress --profile --bail --env.prod",
    "build:dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js  --progress --profile",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run build:vendor"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.7",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "3.0.2",
    "@types/hammerjs": "2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.41",
    "@types/node": "6.0.63",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.33",
    "@types/source-map": "0.1.29",
    "@types/uglify-js": "2.6.28",
    "@types/webpack": "1.12.36",
    "X-editable": "git://github.com/vitalets/x-editable",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.2.4",
    "angular-router-loader": "0.4.0",
    "angular2-platform-node": "2.0.11",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-webpack": "1.0.27",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "3.5.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-colorpicker": "2.5.1",
    "bootstrap-duallistbox": "git://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-duallistbox",
    "bootstrap-markdown": "2.10.0",
    "bootstrap-progressbar": "0.9.0",
    "bootstrap-slider": "9.7.1",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "0.7.1",
    "bootstrap-timepicker": "0.5.2",
    "chart.js": "2.3.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "0.1.15",
    "clockpicker": "0.0.7",
    "clone": "2.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "1.0.0-beta.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.26.1",
    "debounce": "1.0.0",
    "dropzone": "4.3.0",
    "dygraphs": "1.1.1",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "fuelux": "3.15.11",
    "gh-pages": "0.12.0",
    "he": "1.1.1",
    "highcharts": "4.2.7",
    "html-minify-loader": "1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.28.0",
    "ie-shim": "0.1.0",
    "imports-loader": "0.6.5",
    "ion-rangeslider": "2.1.6",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
    "jquery": "2.2.4",
    "jquery-color": "1.0.0",
    "jquery-jcrop": "0.9.13",
    "jquery-knob": "1.2.11",
    "jquery-ui-npm": "1.12.0",
    "jquery-validation": "1.16.0",
    "jquery.maskedinput": "1.4.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "2.2.2",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "0.1.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.8.0",
    "markdown": "0.5.0",
    "morris.js": "0.5.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.3.3",
    "ng2-popover": "0.0.13",
    "ng2-redux": "4.2.1",
    "nouislider": "8.5.1",
    "oidc-client": "1.3.0",
    "parse5": "2.2.3",
    "protractor": "4.0.14",
    "raphael": "2.2.7",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.9",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "5.1.0",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "1.7.1",
    "script-loader": "0.7.0",
    "scriptjs": "2.5.8",
    "select2": "4.0.3",
    "smartadmin-plugins": "1.0.15",
    "source-map-loader": "0.1.6",
    "string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "summernote": "0.8.2",
    "to-markdown": "3.0.3",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "0.8.2",
    "ts-node": "1.7.3",
    "tslint": "3.15.1",
    "tslint-loader": "2.1.5",
    "typedoc": "0.5.5",
    "typescript": "2.1.6",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "v8-lazy-parse-webpack-plugin": "0.3.0",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.16.1",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "1.0.2",
    "zone.js": "0.7.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you use npm@5, does still behave this odd once you check in the `package-lock.json`? (If you need to support npm@4, using shrinkwrap should suffice as well to force a specific version.) Furthermore, do you have an `.npmrc` in the project? If so, post it. Also, what does `npm config list` print?

Comment: And not a solution to your specific problem, more of a workaround, yet unreliable installs are why I dropped npm and use yarn with its yarn.lock instead. Also great performance boost on installs.

Comment: @k0pernikus I'll have to update and see if I can catch a package-lock.json with the right jquery package. That might work since it includes an integrity hash, but part of the problem is these two packages have the same version. I've tried filling the dependencies of the unofficial package but that was a deep rabbit hole I never found the bottom of. Also working on specifying the official package as a git dependency but running into some other troubles. It's a large SPA template so I don't have a great grasp on the dependency tree, and I'm a bit green with JS in general.

Comment: @k0pernikus `package-lock.json` is identical for both versions of the jquery 2.2.4 package. They both have the same SHA1 hash.